# Vertical Align of images in Quarto Presentations

Tags: css, r, quarto, reveal.js

I am using quarto presentations with `revealjs` format.
I have no problem setting images to be horizontally centered like so

```
![](img/path_to_img.svg){fig-align="center" height="200"}
```

I am trying to get the figure vertically aligned to center but I can't find a way to.
If I try to tweak the css of the slide by changing the class to `.center`, it does center the content vertically, but it centers *all* content and not just the image.

How do I vertically center the image?

Things I have tried:

- adding `style="padding-top: 150px;` helps to kinda center it, but it's eye-balling
- adding `vertical-align: middle;` does not seem to work

Comment: Using absolute positioning could be a solution here:
https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#absolute-position

Comment: @cderv Indeed, very similar solution to my `padding-top`, I wonder why this is the most straight-forward solution from quarto docs rather than having a proper middle alignment (it's probably because I don't understand what's going on in the background enough).

Comment: I think there is no such middle alignment feature because revealjs does not have that built-in. You can open a feature request to have a more built in way to do that probably.
We have a default of stretching the image to fill the available space though (https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#stretch) which make the image center on the slide obviously

Answer (score 8):

You can create some space above and below of the image, so that it looks like a v-align and to do that you need to use `layout` as following.

Here `layout="[[-1], [1], [-1]]"` translates to,

> create three rows with 1st and 3rd row as empty space and 2nd row with one column.

See [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#complex-layouts) in the quarto docs to know more about Layouts.

```
---
title: "Vertical align"
format: revealjs
---


## Image alignment (Default)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus ultrices
leo sit amet accumsan.

![](https://placeholder.pics/svg/200){fig-align="center" height=200}


## Vertically Aligned 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam luctus ultrices
leo sit amet accumsan.

::: {layout="[[-1], [1], [-1]]"}

![](https://placeholder.pics/svg/200){fig-align="center"}

:::
```

---

[image: Vertical Image alignment]

---

Comment: This is an option, though `{.absolute top=50 right=50 width="450" height="250"}` sounds like something I can play with easier than making layouts